# Handling Form Submission in Gradle for Objects

Tags: java, spring, forms, object

I assume you well versed with Spring and also knowledgeable with [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/).

My goal is to dispatch Java objects like a list, a table or an image and call some function with them as parameters.

However neither the Thymeleaf document nor the Spring Documentation contain such complex cases and thus I am at loss.

I would be helped, if one could provide the neccessary syntax in the Java Greeting class to dispatch an ArrayList, store them first in the html script, calling functions on them with them as parameters. I am not interested in anything fancy, but just the syntax.

Below the simplistic code for a quick reference.

Jave Code:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
</script>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

To ensure the high quality of Stack Overflow I strongly recommend reading [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) first before commenting or answering. If you have nothing constructive to say, leave. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "To ensure the high quality of Stack Overflow I strongly recommend reading this article here first before commenting or answering." - I can appreciate you being a steward of this fine site, but why do you feel the need to say something like this? It, in fact, immediately lowers the quality of your question.

Comment: Now for my more "constructive" comment: it is not clear what you are asking for at all. "dispatch an ArrayList, store them first in the html script, calling functions on them with them as parameters". What does this mean?

Comment: I am aware of this sad fact. However I consider it far more dangerous for SO, if answers of low quality are provided. Questions attract answers and comment naturally and thus low quality has to be prevented.

Comment: First I want to dispatch an ArrayList. Then the html script is executed. There I would like my ArrayList to be stored. Then I would like to call a function on it.

Comment: When you say the html "script" is executed, do you mean rendered in a browser? If so, how do you suppose this ArrayList will be "stored"? Finally, what sort of "function" do you want to call on this stored ArrayList?

Comment: @rmlan, quite obvious: He expects something like <script> var a = ${greetings.myList} ; function1(a); function2(b); </script> etc. 
Of course this doesn't work like this, but I leave this to figure out for him himself. The kind of function doesn't seem to matter at all, as said so in the description. And as the examples suggests: Yes, it is rendered in a browser.

Comment: No, it is not obvious. An obvious question would solicit answers fairly quickly, don't you think? Anyways, what you are talking about is arbitrarily rendering a java object as a javascript object, which is not really a common use case for this type of technology. You might look into using AJAX and JSON to accomplish what you would like to do.